# Is it possible to add request/response handlers on SOAP requests/responses using SaaJ?

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, saaj

in my project I have to use **SaaJ** to create requests and to consume the **SOAP** responses.

In **JAX_WS** there was a notion of *handlers* with which on the port you can add additional information for example to add Sequrity header. I was wondering if this possible in the SaaJ case.
 SO my idea is to add WS-Security header before sending the message on SOAPConnection is it possible? Or I have to add special method for example on the SOAPConnection class which to add the header?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](http://people.apache.org/~fadushin/stage/wss4j/1.5.5-RETRACTED/site/apidocs/org/apache/ws/security/message/WSSecHeader.html) provided by apache to create your WS-Security header as a Document and then you can add it to your existing SOAPEnvelope.